# A scenario in which the lifetime and scope of a variable is not related

Tags: scope, lifetime

In some cases, the scope and lifetime of a variable appear to be related. For example, a local variable in a function has scope over the function and also the same lifetime as the activations of the function.
Can you think of a scenario in which the lifetime and scope of a variable is not related? Illustrate your example in any language and state the scope and lifetime of the variable.

One thing that comes to my mind is by using the keyword `global` in python.

```
x = 10
def foo():
    x = 5
    print(x)
foo()
```

in which the output is `5` despite `x` having a global lifetime but not being in the scope of `foo`? But I think that this is not a reasonable answer since we could have just typed `global x` in the function `foo` and changed the value of `x=10` to `x=5`. So, any ideas of legit scenarios?